# I activated all three API Keys on my Etherscan.io account, was I only suppose activate one (1), not three (3)?

Tags: azure-devops, api, devsecops

I am new to web3, cloud, C++, CLI, Meta and Stack. This is all a new world a new platform for me. I have no one on one teacher I started off being a service (gig) worker to Content Creator-to-Developer in matter of the last six months. I learn from trial and error. I signed my new business up with Walmart Marketplace last week and I was denied access to the platform because it said I had too many API accounts or something to that affect. Don't hold me to the exact wording and terminology though, I'm behind on task so I haven't dealt with he issue yet.

However, all that said, it raises my first question above. Basically how many API's could I activate on one platform? Is one enough, or, more equals workflow efficiency?

Answer (score 1):

Organizations who offer an API usually have in place a mechanism to limit your use. For example, they will offer tiers of service at different prices, like:

- Free (for up to 100 requests a day)
- Business (up to 1,000 requests a day)
- Enterprise (unlimited, usually "call us for pricing")

When someone creates multiple accounts, it can look like you are trying to bypass the limits, for example by attempting to use ten free accounts to get 1,000 requests a day.

If you use more requests than you pay for, you will normally get an HTTP 409 response, which means "too many requests". When you create several accounts, you are likely to find they get locked.